# LINQ to SQL vs Entity Framework for an app with a future SQL Azure version

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, azure-sql-database

I've got a vertical market Dot Net Framework 1.1 C#/WinForms/SQL Server 2000 application. Currently it uses ADO.Net and Microsoft's SQLHelper for CRUD operations.

I've successfully converted it to Dot Net Framework 4 C#/WinForms/ SQL Server 2008.   What I'd like to do is also offer my customers the OPTION to use SQL Azure as a backend storage for their data instead of local/LAN SQL Server.

If I know SQL Azure is in my application's future, should I:

A. Switch to LINQ to SQL

or

B. Swith to Entity Framework

or

C. Stick with ADO.Net and SQLHelper

?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to Entity Framework, it works just fine with SQLAzure and is the recommended ORM by Microsoft for .Net 4

Answer (score 0):

ADO.net works just fine,

My personal favorite is Linq2Sql which works fine with azure

Microsoft is now recommending that everyone switch to entity framework